# fatal error at runtime with Realm using LInkingOjbects

Tags: swift, realm, fatal-error

Getting the following fatal error.

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error
>   Domain=io.realm Code=1 "Schema validation failed due to the following
>   errors:
>   - Property 'GearModel.category' declared as origin of linking objects property 'CategoryRepository.gearList' links to type 'CategoryModel'"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Schema validation failed due to the
>   following errors:
>   - Property 'GearModel.category' declared as origin of linking objects property 'CategoryRepository.gearList' links to type 'CategoryModel',
>   Error Code=1}:

Object models here: Gear Model is assigned to ONE only Category

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class GearModel: Object{

    dynamic var gearID = NSUUID().uuidString
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var manufacturer = ""
    dynamic var sortOrder = 0
    dynamic var category: CategoryModel?

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {return "gearID"}
    }
```

Category Model:  Trying to get list of all GearModel Items with the Category assigned.

```
    import Foundation
    import RealmSwift

    class CategoryModel: Object{

        dynamic var categoryID = NSUUID().uuidString
        dynamic var sortOrder = 0
        dynamic var name = ""
        let gearList = LinkingObjects(fromType: GearModel.self, property: "category")

override class func primaryKey() -> String? {return "categoryID"}
    }
```

Category Repository class: fatal error occurs on line "let realm =...." in the allCategories() func

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class CategoryRepository: CategoryModel{

    class func GetGearItemsForCategory(CategoryID: String) -> Results<GearModel>
    {
        let realm = try! Realm()

        var gearItems = realm.objects(GearModel.self)

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "categoryID = %@", CategoryID)
        gearItems = gearItems.filter(predicate)
        return gearItems
    }

    class func GetCountOfGearItems(CategoryID: String) -> Int
    {
        let realm = try! Realm()

        var gearItems = realm.objects(GearModel.self)

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "categoryID = %@", CategoryID)
        gearItems = gearItems.filter(predicate)
        return gearItems.count
    }

    class func AddCategory(CategoryID: String, Name: String, SortOrder: Int){

        let realm = try! Realm()

        let category = CategoryModel(name: CategoryID, categoryID: Name, sortOrder: SortOrder)

        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(category)
        }
    }

    class func allCategories() -> Results<CategoryModel> {

        let realm = try! Realm()


        return realm.objects(CategoryModel.self).sorted(byProperty: "SortOrder")
    }
```

Comment: The error `Property 'GearModel.categories'...
` suggests that you have another property in GearModel called categories. Where is this?

Comment: Good catch, i had copied in error from one attempt to fix the problem to the error didn't match the code.  Fixed in the code above.  I had changed the relation to from 1 - Many to Many - Many.  Thats why category turned into categories.  But that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you share `CategoryRepository` class as well?

Comment: Added CategoryRepository class.  NOTE: app runs as expected before adding in the LinkingObjects.  So rest of the class should be fine, (I think :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheriting from a class which has `LinkingObjects` properties is not supported.

Object and List properties in Realm are not covariant, meaning that they can only point to exactly the specified class, and not subclasses of that class. This means that `GearModel.category` cannot link to `CategoryRepository` objects, but `CategoryRepository` has the inherited `gearList` property which is trying to list the `GearModel` objects which link to it.

In your specific case, it's not clear why `CategoryRepository` is inheriting from `CategoryModel`.

Comment: To be totally honest, I'm new to Swift and the CategoryRepository code is based on a tutorial on Xamarin to which I then added Realm as my data store.  I'll change that tonight and mark the answer should work out as we hope.